# Ошибка чтения памяти при компиляции

Tags: c++

Код ошибки:

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FF727DE25CF in ConsoleApplication.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000000C3639174A0. occurred

Код програмы:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
const int n = 15, N = 2 + n, M = 5 + n;
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    setlocale(0, " ");
    double a[N][M],min,max;
    min = max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <=N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <=M; j++)
        {
            a[i][j] = pow(n, i + j) + pow(n, i - j) - (i + j) * (i - j);
            cout << "a[" << i << "][" << j << "]=" <<  a[i][j] << endl;
            if (a[i][j] < min) min = a[i][j];
            if (a[i][j] < max) max = a[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "Минимальное число" << min << endl;
    cout << "Максимальное число" << max << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Если память меня не подводит, у меня компилятор Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: ошибка появилась когда я добавил  `for (int j = 0; j <  "=" M; j++)`
То что в плапках точнее   j <  M заменил на  j <  **=** M

Comment: Ну так зачем вы сделали эту замену? Разумеется, будет вылет за пределы массива. Чего же вы ожидали? И почему вы называете это "ошибкой при компиляции", когда ошибка у вас явно не при компиляции, а при *выполнении*? И что в вашем коде делает это `srand(time(NULL));`?

Comment: @AnT хмм просто нужно))) ну да ладно +- работаит пойдет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Каждый из циклов в этом коде будет выполняться на один раз больше, чем необходимо.

Возьмём, к примеру, этот фрагмент для `N = 2`.

```
double a[N];
for (int i = 0; i <=N; i++) {
    a[i];
}
```

условие `i <= N` будет выполняться для значений `0, 1, 2`. То есть для трёх значений. В то время, как размер массива - `2` и, соотевтственно, допустимые индексы для него `0, 1`. Значит доступ к `a[2]` уже будет за пределы массива, что является неопределённым поведением согласно станрту С++. И это поведение проявляется как ошибка времени исполнения представленная здесь.